# I don't see how the binomial theorem relates to the principle of inclusion and exclusion?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution, inclusion-exclusion

I'm learning discrete maths as a hobby at the moment and I got stuck when the tutor starting relating the binomial theorem to the principles of inclusion and exclusion. The video I was watching is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GS7dIWA6Hpo&list=PLDDGPdw7e6Aj0amDsYInT_8p6xTSTGEi2&index=6 and the question starts at (14.25).

I understand the binomial theorem, and I see how combinatorics is used to calculate the coefficients. I've seen multiple online tutorials where the binomial theorem has been used to describe the nature of inclusion and exclusion and I just don't understand.

Exclusion/Inclusion formula:

|A1 ∪ A2 ∪ A3| = |A1| + |A2| + |A3| − |A1 ∩ A2| − |A1 ∩ A3| − |A2 ∩ A3| + |A1 ∩ A2 ∩ A3|

This makes sense because we have to exclude the cases where elements are counted twice (drawing venn diagrams helped me understand this).

Binomial Theorem:

$(A+B)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose{k}} A^{n-k} B^{k}$

This formula makes sense to me again, but can someone please explain it to me in simple terms how the binomial theorem is even related to inclusion/exclusion?

I've also seen proofs where examples substitute the `x = 1` and `y = -1` and we end up getting the binomial expansion to equal 0. I just don't see how we can relate that to PIE.

Please help.

EDIT:

This part of the video is what confuses me (17.27). I don't get the ((1) + (-1)) part, what is he trying to show from that?

Comment: Try expanding $0=(1-1)^n$ by the binomial theorem.

Comment: I did, the evens cancel out the odds. I just don't see how it applies to PIE.

Comment: I though the video explained it pretty well. When you count how many times an element $x$ which satisfies $r>0$ conditions is counted in the complicated summation on the right hand side of PIE, you get a certain binomial summation $\binom{r}0-\binom{r}1+\dots+(-1)^r\binom{r}r$, which you can prove is equal to $0$ using the binomial theorem. What part of that is confusing you?

Comment: This part of the video is what confuses me (17.27). I don't get the ((1) + (-1)) part, what is he trying to show from that?

Comment: Just seems strange that he will jump to (x + y)^n and show ((1) + (-1))^n = 0. That equation makes sense in relation to the binomial theorem but what does the values of x and y even have anything to do with the question at hand?

Comment: There is not really a deep connection here, I don't think. The point is that the speaker came accross the summation $\binom{r}0-\binom{r}1+\dots\pm\binom{r}r$ and wanted to simplify it. It turned out that when you take the binomial theorem $(x+y)^r=\sum_{k=0}^r\binom{r}kx^ky^{n-k}$, and plug in $x=1,y=-1$, the result on the right hand side of the equation is exactly the summation they wanted to simplify, while the left hand side is zero. You get more used to tricks like these after you see them a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the example of finding the number of numbers not divisible by $2,3,5$, the inclusion-exclusion principle is:
$$\bar{N}=N-N(2)-N(3)-N(5)+N(2,3)+N(2,5)+N(3,5)+N(2,3,5)=\\
100-50-33-20+16+10+6-3=26.$$
In this problem let's see how many times the central region (which contains the numbers divisible by $2,3,5$ simultaneously) is counted. The teacher calls this region by $x$. By $r$ the teacher considers the number of numbers (i.e. $2,3,5$), that is $r=3$. So:
$${r\choose 0}={3\choose 0}=1 \ \ \ \text{in} \  N \ \\
\text{(i.e. in the whole universal set)};\\
{r\choose 1}={3\choose 1}=3 \ \ \text{in} \ N(2)+N(3)+N(4) \ \\
\text{(i.e. in each of the three regions)};\\
{r\choose 2}={3\choose 2}=3 \ \ \text{in} \ N(2,3)+N(2,5)+N(3,5) \ \\
\text{(i.e. in each of the pairwise intersections of the three regions)};\\
{r\choose 3}={3\choose 3}=1 \ \ \text{in} \ N(2,3,5) \ \\
\text{(i.e. in the common intersection of the three regions)}.$$ 
Now the inclusion-exclusion formula for the number of times the region $x$ is counted looks like:
$$\begin{align}x&={r\choose 0}-{r\choose 1}+{r\choose 2}-{r\choose 3}=\\
&={3\choose 0}-{3\choose 1}+{3\choose 2}-{3\choose 3}=\color{red}{1-3+3-1=0}=\\
&={3\choose 0}\cdot 1^3\cdot (-1)^0+{3\choose 1}\cdot 1^2\cdot (-1)^1+{3\choose 2}\cdot 1^1\cdot (-1)^2+{3\choose 3}\cdot 1^0\cdot (-1)^3=\\
&=(1-1)^3=0.\end{align}$$
The aim of the teacher for using the binomial expansion of $(1-1)^3$ is to explain in an easy way that the sum is zero, $\color{red}{\text{rather than calculating each term and adding}}$.

Comment: Thanks, It's confusing to grasp at first but I think I get it!

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

The explanation goes back to the origins of Boolean algebra. Define a "Boolean" variable $\, x \,$ as one where $\, x^2 = x. \,$ For these variables $\, 1-x \,$ denotes logical negation and $\, xy \,$ denotes logical and. Finally, by [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws),
$\ 1-(1-x)(1-y) \,$ denotes logical or.

In the context of subsets of a univeral set $\, U, \,$ any subset $\, A \,$ of $\, U \,$ is identified by its [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) $\, A(x) \,$ which is Boolean valued. Now the number of elements of $\, A \,$ is $\, |A| = \sum A(x) .\,$ Next, the indicator function of $\, A \cap B \,$ is $\, A(x)B(x), \,$ of complement of $\, A \,$ is $\, 1-A(x), \,$ and of $\, A \cup B \,$ is $\, 1-(1-A(x))(1-B(x)). \,$

Given any subsets $\, A_1, A_2, \dots, A_n \,$ and  their indicator functions $\, A_1(x), A_2(x), \dots, A_n(x), \,$  we can write
$\, 1-(1-A_1(x))(1-A_2(x)) = A_1(x) + A_2(x) - A_1(x)A_2(x) \,$ which implies $\, |A_1 \cap A_2| = |A_1| + |A_2| - |A_1 \cup A_2|. \,$ This obviously generalizes to any finite number of subsets and is
one form of the PIE.

Now suppose that $\,A = A_1=A_2=\dots=A_n.\,$
Use the binomial theorem to get
$$ (1-A(x))^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose{k}} (-1)^k A(x)^{k}$$
but since $\,A(x)\,$ and $\,1-A(x)\,$ are Boolean valued
and if **also** $\,n>0\,$ this simplifies to
$$ 1-A(x) = (1-A(x))^n = 1 + A(x)\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose{k}} (-1)^k.$$
If now $\,A(x)\ne 0\,$ then this implies that
$$ -1 = \sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose{k}} (-1)^k \qquad \text{ and } \qquad
0 = \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose{k}} (-1)^k . $$

Answer (score 1):

In Goulden-Jackson approach, the PIE looks like :

$N(x)=E(x+1)$

For the considered example we have the "exact generating function"

$E(x) = 26  + 48x + 32x^2 + 3x^3$

since we have 26 numbers that are not divisible with 2 or 3 or 5, 48 numbers that are divisible with **exactly** one of {2,3, 5}, 32 numbers divisible with **exactly** two of them and three numbers divisible with 2 and 3 and 5.

$N(x) = 100  + 103x + 32x^2 + 3x^3$

is the "at least" generating function for numbers that are divisible with **at least** zero, one, two or three of {2,3,5}

We have to obtain the 26 knowing 100, 103 = 50 + 33 + 20, 32 = 16 + 6 + 10 and 3

Well, by Goulden-Jackson, $26 = E(0) = N(-1) = 100-103+32-3$

One may see that the binomial coefficients occur in $E(x+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

We start out by adding up $|A_1|+|A_2|+\dots+|A_n|$.  Then we say, "Wait any element in to subsets have been counted twice; we have to subtract those."  So we subtract $|A_1\cap A_2|+|A_1\cap A_3|+\dots+A_{n-1}\cap A_n|$  But wait.  Any element in $3$ subsets has been added $3$ times and subtracted ${3\choose2}$ times, so it hasn't been counted at all, so we have to add them back in.  But then an element of $4$ subsets has been counted ${4\choose1}-{4\choose2}+{4\choose3}=2$ times so we have to subtract those.  Do you see where this is going?

Comment: Could you give me an example of 4 subsets in binomial coefficient terms?

Comment: Basically just the the start to finish to show the distinct counts

Comment: This part of the video is what confuses me (17.27). I don't get the ((1) + (-1)) part, what is he trying to show from that?

Comment: Just seems strange that he will jump to (x + y)^n and show ((1) + (-1))^n = 0. That equation makes sense in relation to the binomial theorem but what does the values of x and y even have anything to do with the question at hand?

Comment: I haven't watched the video, so I can't comment on it.  As for giving an example of $4$ subsets, I thought that's what I was doing at the end of the answer.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: Never mind, thanks.